# OctoberCms установить tailwind

Tags: octobercms, tailwind

Использую october cms. Инструкцию которую предлагают на сайте чтобы запустить локальный сервер без docker требуют лицензию. Воспользовался docker, все запустил сервер бесплатно все работает. Но он создает контейнер в изолированной среде, которую я открываю через VSCode Dev Containers. Но сразу же возникает вопрос:

Как сюда установить tailwind если даже nmn недоступен, хотя в (root/www/html) корне проекта есть package.json есть скрипты из npm да и webpack.config присутствует. И установка тем недоступна (наверное хочет лицензию), хотя там и есть какой то туториал.